# Create Reset Azure AD Password functionality

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I wanted to create Azure AD Reset Password Functionality from our portal. We have Microsoft login screen while login to portal. From that screen user can reset password and navigate to MS Azure AD reset screen with email automatic filled up.

I want to implement same functionality (navigate to this screen with dynamic email id(selected user email id).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is Azure AD **self-service password reset** feature, we can enable this via Azure classic portal. More information about SSPR, refer the link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-sspr